# Is there a way in React native to set a state variable based on data that is a constant

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Is there a way in React native to set a state variable based on data that is a constant ?
Is there a different method to do this ?

If temp<32, it sets style as cold else as warm.
I am getting error if I do this code.

```
const App = ({ props }) => {
  const Temperature = 25;
  const [Tstyle, setTstyle] = useState();

  const func = () => {
    if (Temperature < 32) setTstyle(stylesheet.cold);
    else setTstyle(stylesheet.warm);
  };

  return <View style={Style}>{Temperature}</View>;
};
```

Comment: Please provide the error

Comment: Yes provide the `error` you got.

Answer (score 0):

use state:

```
const [Tstyle, setTstyle] = useState();
```

but you use Style instead of Tstyle:

```
return <View style={Style}>{Temperature}</View>;
```

so change Style to Tstyle:

```
 return <View style={Tstyle}>{Temperature}</View>;
```